# Ожидание перед действием discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Есть команда, нужно выполнить следующее действие по истечению условного таймера, пытался гуглить - не понял.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clear(ctx, count = 50):
    await ctx.send('Сейчас через какое то время делитнуца сообщения')
    #таймер
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = count+2)
```

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep(count)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Импортируем `import asyncio` после используем где нужно `await asyncio.sleep(count)` на примере этого кода:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clear(ctx, count = 50):
    await ctx.send('Сейчас через какое то время делитнуца сообщения')
    await asyncio.sleep(2) #следующее действие произойдёт по истечению времени
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = count+2)
```